# “If it is or is going to be/ will be in stock”

Tags: conditionals, future-constructions

1. Now, I will first check  if the CD I'd like to buy is
   or **is going to be** in your stock before ordering in the USA.
2. Now, I will first check  if the CD I'd like to buy is
   or **will be** in your stock before ordering in the USA.

Is *will* possible in the subordinate clause?
I think that second sentence with "will be" is not possible here because it is an *if* sentence .

Comment: _Will_ is only appropriate if you are talking about a future action. "Before I order that CD next week, I will check...". You want to know whether it **is** in stock at the time of ordering.

Comment: Is going to be ok if the record is not in stock now but will be in the future.

Comment: Certainly it is, if you are prepared to wait for them to order a new supply.

Comment: my question was more of the use of will , I think in my example will will sound awkward

Comment: You need to structure your question a lot more carefully. It's hard to tell which part you're asking about, as you don't separate quotes from speculation & question. Presenting alternatives in bold really doesn't help. Make two quotes, one for each interpretation, then ask about them separately, with reasoning. The whole thing is difficult to read & comprehend.

Comment: I want to know if" will be" is possible in my bolded example

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine with "will" for two reasons.

First, "if" here is used in the sense of "whether", and the rule about not using "will" doesn't apply to the meaning of "whether".

Second, even a conditional sentence with "if" can have "will":

> Can you assure me that the CD will be in stock in the next month? I'll order from you if it will be in stock.

The rule about not using "will" with "if" only applies when *the condition is a future event*. Most of the time, the "will" verb describes a future event, as in, "*We'll move the party inside if **it rains**.*" But in this case, the condition is not a future event. The condition is *the present knowledge* of a future state. The buyer is making the decision now based on present knowledge of what's going to happen. It means something more like,

> I'll order from you if **I know that** it will be in stock in the future.

The present knowledge is the condition, not the arrival of the CD in the future.